# Почему resolver не блокирует переход?

Tags: javascript, angular2

В моём приложении 2 странички. Переход с первой на вторую я защитил резолвером. Он получает список пользователей гитхаба и если запрос был успешным, то происходит переход, а если нет - происходит редирект на страницу1:

```
@Injectable()
export class ResolverService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private router: Router) {}

  resolve(): any {
    const users = this.httpClient.get('https://api.github.com/users_').subscribe(
      (next) => {
        console.log(next);
        return next;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('error');
        this.router.navigate(['/page1']);
        return null;
      }
    );
  }  

}
```

В коде выше я специально сделал ошибку в адресе запроса. И ожидал такую последовательность событий:

пользователь находится на страничке1

он нажимает ссылку, ведущую на страничку2

срабатывает роутинги резолвер

резолвер не получает данные из-за ошибки в запросе. следовательно срабатывает редирект на страничку 1

Но проблема в том, что в реальности после того как пользователь на жал на ссылку и отработал резолвер, всё же происходит переход на страничку2 и пользователь долю секунды её видит. а затем происходит редирект и пользователь снова отказывается на страничке1

Не совсем понятно в чём смысл резолвера. Ведь для того и придуман разработчиками ангуляра чтобы не показывать пользователю следующую страничку до тех пор пока не выяснится получены данные или нет

что я сделал не так? вот мой остальной код:
роутинг:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/page1', pathMatch : 'full'},
  {path : 'page1', component : Page1Component},
  {
    path : 'page2', 
    component : Page2Component, 
    resolve: {
      users: ResolverService
    }   
  }
];
```

компонент странички2:

```
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private resolverService: ResolverService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.data['users'];
  }
```

шаблон корневого компонента:

```
<a class="link" [routerLink]="'/page1'">page1</a>
<a class="link" [routerLink]="'/page2'">page2</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

тут [минимальный пример](https://github.com/zlodiak/resolver_fail) в виде репозитория на гитхабе

Comment: приведите минимальный выполнимый пример на гитхабе. И попробуйте написать в резолвере `return this.httpClient.get...` вместо константы `users`, которая там совсем не нужна

Comment: @НазарКалитюк добавил в конец вопроса

Comment: мне кажется ты уже спрашивал про резолверы. Покажи в своем коде место, где возвращается ответ **из функции resolve**. Это раз, посмотри наконец справку по Resolve и что он должен возвращать

Comment: Сравни свой код. с [кодом в справке](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard)

Comment: Для проверки, можно или нельзя зайти на страницу нужно использовать `Guard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) - это интерфейс, имплементация которого может использоваться для предоставления данных нужному роуту.

Как видно из определения:

```
interface Resolve<T> { 
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T
}
```

Функция `resolve` может возвращать три вида данных:

1. `Observable<T>`
2. `Promise<T>`
3. `T`

При этом влияние на переход могут оказывать **только** первые два, так как у них может быть *состояние ошибки*. (error в Observalbe, reject в Promise)

Если вернуться к коду в вопросе:

```
resolve(): any {
    const users = this.httpClient.get('https://api.github.com/users_').subscribe(
      (next) => {
        console.log(next);
        return next;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('error');
        this.router.navigate(['/page1']);
        return null;
      }
    );
}
```

Как здесь видно, функция `resolve` **ничего** не возвращает, что равносильно возврату `undefine`. Это значение подходит под тип `T` из выше указанного списка.

Для решения нужно как минимум добавить `return` в функцию.

Но в данном случае это тоже не поможет, так как `users` тут - это результат вызова `subscribe` и не является `Observable`.

Вместо этого можно обратиться к [примеру в справке](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard) и увидеть, что там вместо `subsсribe` используется `map`.

Comment: кажется, теперь понял. а не подскажете в какой ситуации может быть полезно возвратить не observable или promise, а третий тип данных(Т)?

с первыми двумя понятно: пользователь нажал на ссылку, подождал данных, если они пришли, то попал на страницу. но в случае типа Т, данные хоть придут, хоть не придут, но пользователь в любом случае попадёт на страничку. при чём тут резольвер не понятно

Comment: @cyklop77,  суть резолвера не в том, попадет или не попадет на страницу, а в том, чтобы  передать данные в роутъ